# Language switch changed to super key, after dist upgrade

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 20.10, language-support

I had upgraded my **Ubuntu 20.04** to **20.10**.

In the middle of the process, a dialogue showed up and asked that which button combination I want to choose for switching between Latin and national languages. I did accidentally choose the **Super** key.

And now, the Super key changes the input method and does not work combined with any other keys. Even in shortcut settings, I can not change the behaviour!

I just want to set the Super key to open the app drawer as it did default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and replace the line starting with

```
XKBOPTIONS
```

with

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Also, run this command to clear the related user settings:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Comment: you really saved me. thanks a lot.

Comment: you saved my Day! Thank you <3